# How to PUT (save) object to REST endpoint using Restangular

Tags: restangular

Given I have resource id and data as plain JSON, how do I save that JSON to /cars/123/ ???

There seem to be no clear explanation. I don't have restangular element.
restangularizeElement might be the option, but it lacks any meaningful documentation.

All I know is that I want to save {make: 'honda', color: 'now blue, was red'} for car_id == 123.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have plain object you cannot use Restangular [save](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#element-methods) function to update (it will make put request as object has id) object.

Easiest way to achieve it construct your end point url then call put function...

```
Restangular.one('cars', 123).customPUT(carObject).then(function(response){
   TO-DO
})
```

If you want to restangularized your plain object you can use this one...

```
Restangular.restangularizeElement(null,carObject, 'cars').put().then(function (response) {
   TO-DO
})
```

The comman way should be like this. Whenever you get object from backend with `get` or `getList` your object will be **Restangularized** unless you do not choose to turn them plain object by calling `.plain()` method of Restangular response. Then you can safely call `.save()` and it will automatically will be `put` or `post` accordingly...

Comment: Actually, this does not work. .put([queryParams]) is a problem. It put with carobject as query params.

Comment: This works, but is ugly: Restangular.restangularizeElement(null, car, 'cars' + '/' + '123').put(); I tried this: Restangular.restangularizeElement(null, group, Restangular.one('cars', id)).put(); but it uses object in URL. Would be nice if there was some sort of Restangular.one('cars', '123').getUrl(); or something like that.

Comment: @Rastio you can use it like this Restangular.restangularizeElement(null,carObject, 'cars') check edited version of my answer again...

Comment: RE: Restangular.restangularizeElement(null,carObject, 'cars'). What about the car_id? Where does that come into play?

Comment: @Rastio when you have restangularized object and call put function of that element Restangular automatically add its id at the end of url...

Comment: yes, and as indicated in my answer below, it has to be set. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me. Thanks to @wickY26:

```
updateGroup: function (group, id_optional) {
    if (!group.hasOwnProperty('restangularCollection')) {
        // safe to assume it is NOT restangular element; sadly instanceof won't work here
        // since there is no element class
        // need to restangularize
        group = Restangular.restangularizeElement(null, group, ENDPOINT);
        group.id = id_optional;
    }

    return group.put();
},
```